# Direct sum problem

Tags: vector-spaces

In vector space $\mathbb{R} ^ \mathbb{R} =\left\{ f \mid f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \right\} $ let  L be a set of even functions $( f(-t)=f(t))$ and  and M a set of odd functions
 $( f(-t)=-f(t))$ .It's easy to prove that L and M are subspaces of the vector space but how do I prove that 
$\mathbb{R} ^ \mathbb{R} = M \oplus L$ ? It's easy to prove that nul function is in the intersection of M and L but how can a function that isn't even or odd be a sum of two functions that are even or odd. For example the exponential function $ e^x$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are able to write $f$ as the sum of an even function $g$ and an odd function $h$; then, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
f(t)&=g(t)+h(t)\\
f(-t)&=g(-t)+h(-t)=g(t)-h(t)
\end{align}
Can you go on?

Comment: Does this mean that not every function can be written in this form? For example $ e^x + \frac{1}{e^x} $ would then have to be an even function which  it isn't.

Comment: @user15269 No, *every* function can be written as a sum of an even and an odd function; if the function is even to begin with, the “odd part” is the constant zero function (which is odd, isn't it?)

Comment: Thanks I get it